# prove $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{a_i}\ge (n-1)\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}}$

Tags: inequality, summation, contest-math, rearrangement-inequality

prove $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{a_i}\ge ({n-1})\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}}$$ if $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+a_i}=1$$

My try: i tried substituiting  $y_i=\frac{1}{1+a_i}$ thus $\sum y_i=1$

also rearranging inequality we have to prove $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\sqrt{a_i}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}})\ge n\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}}$$

putting value in terms of $y_i$  $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{y_i(1-y_i)}}\ge n\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\sqrt{y_i}}{\sqrt{1-y_i}}$$.i am stuck now i dont know which inequality to use.i tried using A-M$\ge$ H-M inequality.

source ' inequalities A mathematical Olympiad approach'

Comment: Is the index $i=0$ correct for the RHS?

Comment: @user Most likely not. Summation should go from $1$ to $n$ on both sides and it should involve a family of strictly positive reals indexed over the natural interval $[1, n]$.

Comment: @user typo corrected!

Comment: Are you sure about that re-arrangement?

Comment: @Gary not only that, but we could do with more detailed references: where does this inequality come from? what is its background?

Comment: your rearrangement is wrong. What you have rearranged, that is easy to prove but the rearrangement is not the same as original question.

Comment: it comes from " inequalities A mathematical Olympiad approach

Comment: @Math Lover i have fixed it

Comment: There are several solutions on AoPS: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%5Csqrt%7Ba_i%7D%5Cge%20(%7Bn-1%7D)%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Ba_i%7D%7D%24&p=1. – E.g. here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h33608p208903 and here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h5592

Comment: @Quantum Thank you for the reference. Not wanting to spoil the fun of the challenge, but the problem book in question is accessible online and also seems to include a full list of solutions to the exercises proposed...

Comment: yes i know  but the solution is very complicated .i am looking for a simpler solution

Comment: it involves double summing and i am not very familiar with that

Comment: @Quantum: as a word of pedagogic advice, it is then a clear understanding of general summation that you should seek for, rather than shortcut solutions to this or that particular contest inequality. The distinction you seem to make between ''simple'' summation and ''double'' summation is ultimately artificial, to the effect that not understading the latter very well brings into question to what extent you understand the former to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum \limits_{i=i}^{n}\frac{1}{1+a_i}=1$ ...(i)

So $a_i \gt 0$ for all $i \in (1, n)$ and for $n \gt 1$.

We have to prove $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{a_i}\ge ({n-1})\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}}$

or prove, $\sum _\limits{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{1 + a_i}{\sqrt{a_i}} \ge n\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt a_i}}$

or prove, $(\sum _\limits{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{1 + a_i}{\sqrt{a_i}}) \, (\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{1+a_i}) \ge n\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1+a_i}{\sqrt a_i}{\frac{1}{1+a_i}}$ ...(ii)

WLOG, assume, $a_i \le a_{i+1}$ for $1 \le i \le (n-1)$.

Say, $f(a_i) = \dfrac {1+a_i}{\sqrt a_i} = \sqrt a_i + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt a_i}$. So, for all $a_i \gt 0$, $f(a_i) = f(\dfrac{1}{a_i})$

Say, $g(a_i) = \dfrac {1}{1+a_i}$. We can see $g(a_{i+1}) \le g(a_i)$.

**We can see $g(a_i)$ is non-increasing. We now need to prove that $f(a_i)$ is non-decreasing. With that (ii) holds good as per Chebyshev's inequality.**

It is easy to see that the function is non-decreasing for $a_i \gt 1$. It is also easy to see that $a_i$ can be $\lt 1$ only for one value of $i$, **at max**, due to given condition (i).

Say, $a_1 \lt 1$. We also know that $\dfrac {1}{1+a_2} \le 1 - \dfrac {1}{1+a_1} = \dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{a_1}}$.

So, $a_2 \ge \dfrac{1}{a_1}$ and $f(a_1) = f(\dfrac{1}{a_1}) \le f(a_2) \le ... \le f(a_n)$

**With this, we prove that (ii) holds good as per Chebyshev's inequality.**

Comment: I lost at first that important detail assuming $f$ not decreasing as a simple condition. I've now rielaborated my answer including that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Rearrangement works again!

Let $a_i=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i-x_i}{x_i},$ where $i\in\{1,2,...,n-1\}$ and $x_1$, $x_2$,...,$x_n$  are positives.

Thus, $a_n=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i-x_n}{x_n}$ and we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i-x_i}{x_i}}\geq(n-1)\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{x_i}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i-x_i}}$$ and since the last inequality is homogeneous, we can assume that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i=n$ and we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{n-x_i}{x_i}}\geq(n-1)\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{x_i}{n-x_i}}$$ or
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sqrt{\frac{n-x_i}{x_i}}-(n-1)\sqrt{\frac{x_i}{n-x_i}}\right)\geq0$$
or
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1-x_i}{\sqrt{x_i(n-x_i)}}\geq0.$$
Now, let $x_1\leq x_2\leq...\leq x_n.$

Thus, for $i>j$ we have $$1-x_i\leq1-x_j$$ and $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_i(n-x_i)}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_j(n-x_j)}}$$ because the last it's $$x_j(n-x_j)\geq x_i(n-x_i)$$ or
$$(x_i-x_j)(n-x_i-x_j)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Thus, $(1-x_1,1-x_2,...,1-x_n)$ and $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1(n-x_1)}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_2(n-x_2)}},...,\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n(n-x_n)}}\right)$ have the same ordering and by Chebyshov we obtain:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1-x_i}{\sqrt{x_i(n-x_i)}}\geq\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(1-x_i)\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_i(n-x_i)}}=0$$ and we are done!

Comment: @Explicitly what is the family $x$ in relation to the given family $a$? how do you introduce it, how do you justify its existence? From the point of view of full rigour, that would be the only observation I have to make regarding your argument.

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{a_i}\ge ({n-1})\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}} \iff \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\sqrt{a_i}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}}\right)\ge n\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}}$$

and since

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+a_i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}}+\sqrt{a_i}}=1$$

by [Chebyshev's Inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Chebyshev%27s_Inequality) we obtain

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\sqrt{a_i}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}}\right)\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}}+\sqrt{a_i}}\ge n\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}}$$

indeed assuming wlog $a_i$ not decreasing by $x=\sqrt{a_i}$ we have that

- $f(x)=f\left(\frac1{x}\right)=x+\frac1x \implies f'(x)=1-\frac1{x^2}$ is not decreasing for $x\ge 1$
- $g(x)=\frac{\frac1x}{x+\frac1x}=\frac1{x^2+1}$ is not increasing

moreover we have that

$$\frac{1}{1+a_1}+\frac{1}{1+a_2}\le 1 \iff a_1a_2\ge 1 \iff \sqrt{a_1a_2}\ge 1\iff \sqrt{a_2}\ge\frac1{\sqrt{a_1}}$$

therefore if $a_1\le1$ we have that

$$f(\sqrt{a_1})= f\left(\frac1{\sqrt{a_1}}\right)\le f(\sqrt{a_2})$$

and the condition for the application of the inequality is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

For this solution, I will only use [this inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Titu%27s_Lemma), AM-GM Inequality and C-S.
We need to prove that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{a_i}\ge ({n-1})\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}}$$
if
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+a_i}=1$$

**Case I: Assume $a_i\geq1$ for all $i$ till $n$**

$$1=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+a_i}\geq {n^2\over n+\sum_{i=0}^n{a_i}}\Rightarrow \sum_{i=0}^n{a_i}\geq n(n-1)\Rightarrow n+\sum_{i=0}^n{a_i}\geq n(n-1)+n$$

$$ \Rightarrow 2\sum_{i=0}^n{\sqrt{a_i}}\geq n(n-1)+n $$

As $\sum_{i=0}^n{\sqrt{a_i}}\geq n$,

$$ \sum_{i=0}^n{\sqrt{a_i}}\geq n(n-1) $$

Now it's enough to prove that

$$ n(n-1)\geq (n-1)\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}} \Rightarrow n \geq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}}$$ which is obvious for this case.

**Case II:**
Assume that some $a_i \ge 1$ and others $\le 1$.
Note that, as mentioned in @MathLover's solution, only one $a_i$ can be $\leq 1$.
Let $a_1$ be less than $1$  and rename others $a_{2},...,a_n$ where $1\leq k\leq n$.
Just to reduce this case hence the solution, the cases that arise in this case are left, as resolving them is very easy, in the sense that they are similar to resolving case I as before. (and the other is very easy)
Just assume $$\frac{1}{1+a_1}=p,0\leq p\leq 1$$ for one case in this case, and $$\sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{1}{1+a_i}=1-p,0\leq 1-p\leq 1$$ for the other. Just prove the original inequality for these two cases, and sum up the hypotheses and the inequalities to get what was desired. Done!

Comment: And what about if some $a_i$ is $<1$ and others $>1$?

Comment: @user Now is my solution correct? I updated it on your advice.

Comment: I'll take a look to that!

Comment: case 2 is not valid given the condition $\sum \dfrac {1}{1+a_i} = 1$. Also, in case 3, you can have only one $a_i$ less than 1.

Comment: @MathLover Would you explain in more detail what you want to say?

Comment: say $a_1 \lt 1$. Then $\dfrac {1}{1+a_1} \gt \dfrac {1}{2}$. Then rest of the the series has to add to less than half so all other $a_i$ will be greater than $1$.

Comment: So you can simplify your solution, that was my point really.

Comment: @MathLover Yes.... You are right. I decide to reduce my solution to case I and add your point, but not today. It's late night. I will do it tomorrow.